# React, call multiple components inside component <componentA><componentB></componentA>

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm trying to create a menu in which I have main categories, and then secondary categories. Inside main categories I want to invoke the sub categories with their own information

```
<MainCategory title="Home">
    <SubCategory title="welcome message">
    <SubCategory title="about">
<MainCategory />

<MainCategory title="Contact">
    <SubCategory title="Social">
    <SubCategory title="E-Mail">
    <SubCategory title="Stores">
<MainCategory />
```

Main category:

```
<div className="collapse show" id="navbar-dashboards">
    <p>{props.title}</p>
    <ul className="nav nav-sm flex-column">
      This is where I want to render different sub categories
    </ul>
</div>
```

What can I do?

Comment: What seems to go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to approach this. One way you've started to detail out in your question:

```js
const MainCategory = (props) => (
    <div className="collapse show" id="navbar-dashboards">
        <p>{props.title}</p>
        <ul className="nav nav-sm flex-column">
            // This is where I wanan render different sub categories
        </ul>
    </div>
);

const SubCategory = (props) => (
    // handle the rendering of SubCategory in its own function
    <div>in render for SubCategory: {props.title}</div>
);

const Main = () => (
    <MainCategory title="Home">
        <SubCategory title="welcome message">
        <SubCategory title="about">
    <MainCategory />

    <MainCategory title="Contact">
        <SubCategory title="Social">
        <SubCategory title="E-Mail">
        <SubCategory title="Stores">
    <MainCategory />
);
```

But the way you've structured your `div` makes me think you're trying something more like:

```
const MainCategory = (props) => (
    <div className="collapse show" id="navbar-dashboards">
        <p>{props.title}</p>
        <ul className="nav nav-sm flex-column">
            // use a loop to render subcategories
            {props.subCategories.map((subCategory) => (
                <div>title: {subCategory}</div>
            );
        </ul>
    </div>
);

const Main = () => (
    <MainCategory title="Home" subCategories={['welcome message', 'about']} />
);
```

There's one more way that's via composition, info and examples on the [React website](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). In short:

> We recommend that such components use the special children prop to pass children elements directly into their output
>
> ```
> function FancyBorder(props) {
>   return (
>     <div className={'FancyBorder FancyBorder-' + props.color}>
>       {props.children}
>     </div>
>   );
> }
>
> function WelcomeDialog() {
>   return (
>     <FancyBorder color="blue">
>       <h1 className="Dialog-title">
>         Welcome
>       </h1>
>       <p className="Dialog-message">
>         Thank you for visiting our spacecraft!
>       </p>
>     </FancyBorder>
>   );
> }
> ```